# SAS date or numeric data?

Tags: sas

```
%let months_back = %sysget(months_back);

data;
        m = intnx('month', "&sysdate9"d, -&months_back - 2, 'begin');
        m = intnx('day', put(m, date9.), 26, 'same');
        m2back = put(m, yymmddd10.);
        put m2back;
run;
```

> NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the
>   places given by: (Line):(Column).
>         5:19 NOTE: Invalid numeric data, '01OCT2012' , at line 5 column 19.

I really don't know why this go wrong. The date string is numeric data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PUT(m, date9.) is the culprit here.  The 2nd argument of INTNX needs to be numeric (i.e. a date), the PUT function always returns a character value, in this instance '01OCT2012'.  Just take out the PUT function completely and the code should work.

```
m = intnx('day', m, 26, 'same');
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the 2nd argument should be numeric and m is already a numeric type. Argument like "01OCT2022"d will be converted to numeric type automatically. The put(m, date9.) return a char value without the decorator 'd' and SAS does not know how to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

SAS stores dates as numbers - and in fact does not have a truly separate type for them.  A SAS date is the number of days since 1/1/1960, so a bit over 19000 for today.  The date format is entirely irrelevant to any date calculations - it is solely for human readibility.

The bit where you say:

```
"&sysdate9"d
```

actually converts the string "01JAN2012" to a numeric value (18304).

There's actually a quicker way to accomplish what you're trying to do.  Because days correspond to whole numbers in SAS, to increment by one day you can simply add one to the value.

For example:

```
%let months_back=5;
data _null_;
        m = intnx('month', today(), -&months_back - 2, 'begin');
        m2 = intnx('day', m, 26, 'same');
        m3 = intnx('month',"&sysdate9"d, -&months_back - 2)+26;
        m2back = put(m2, yymmdd10.);
        put m= date9. m2= yymmdd10. m3= yymmdd10.;
run;
```

M3 does your entire calculation in one step, by using the MONTH interval, then adding 26.  INTNX('day'...) is basically pointless, unless there's some other value to using the function (using a shift index for example).

You also can see the use of a format in the PUT(log) statement here - you don't have to PUT it to a character value and then put that to the log to get the formatted value, just put (var) (format.); - and string together as many as you want that way.

Also, "&sysdate9."d is not the best way to get the current date.  &sysdate. is only defined on startup of SAS, so if your session ran for 3 days you would not be on the current day (though perhaps that's desired?).  Instead, the TODAY() function gets the current date, up to date no matter how long your SAS session has been running.

Finally - I recommend `data _null_;` if you don't want a dataset (and naming the result dataset if you do want it).  `data _null_` does not create a dataset.  data; simply creates increasing numbers of datasets (data1, data2, ...) which quickly fill up your workspace and make it hard to tell what you're doing.